# displaying a value to a calendars dates - Winform

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working with a calendar control to determine which items should be downloaded from a resource. I want to display the total found under each date prior to displaying the calendar, but not sure how to go about this. I'm not sure if I should create a new calendar control to handle this, or if there is already something available. Below is pseudo code that would be similar to what I want to do

```
internal void CalendarDate_AvailableFiles(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
{
    foreach(DateValue day in MonthDisplayed){
        day.Text = fileTotal;
    }
}
```